# Redirect to IDP/Login from OnValidatePrincipal

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am struggling to implement use of refresh tokens in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor application.

Following a few examples, I have put the logic to refresh my access token (with the refresh token) in [OnValidatePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onvalidateprincipal?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

So far this seems to be working.  But when there is an issue (the refresh token is too old, or has already been used, etc), I need the user the login again.

But I am unclear how to redirect the user to the IDP's login screen in a way that my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor application will understand (and hopefully update the authentication cookie).

**In the event of an authentication failure in the OnValidatePrinpal event, how can I redirect to the IDP's login page?**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling these two operations:

```
cookieCtx.RejectPrincipal();
await cookieCtx.HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

`cookieCtx` is the context that is passed into the `OnValidatePrincipal` event.